# Magnitude of a Transfer Function

Tags: transfer-function, frequency-response, pole-zeroplot

So I have an unknown circuit with a plot like this:
[image]

From this I have to determine  a likely transfer function model. It looks to me like there is a pole at 50 rad/sec and a zero at 1500 rad/sec, with a dc gain of 1.

When I plug those into a transfer function I get:
H(s)=  (S+1500)/(S+50) or as H(f) = (j2πf+1500)/(j2πf+50)

How do I find the magnitude of this transfer function?
I've been doing |H(f)| = √((2*π*f)^2+1500^2) / √((2*π*f)^2+80^2) but I am not getting the same magnitude as my plot.

 Please Help!!!!!

Comment: I assume 80 is a typo. Are you entering in radians and Hz properly?

Comment: Curiously same plot found in Russian site , https://5fan-ru.translate.goog/files/13/5fan_ru_69401_848c070892f24b3446ebf185be03585a.html?_x_tr_sch=http&_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-GB&_x_tr_pto=nui

Comment: It's ***j*** \$2\pi f\$, not \$2\pi f\$. You're not calculating the complex absolute value correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

For one, you are not expressing the magnitude in \$dB\$, \$20log10(H)\$ as in your plot.
Try plotting in this form.

$$ |H(w)_{dB}| = 20log10(\sqrt{(1+(w/1500)^2)/(1+(w/50)^2)}) $$

edit. per comment below, you could also write the original tf as

$$H(s=jw) = \frac{1}{30}\frac{(s+1500)}{(s+50)}$$
$$           = \frac{50}{1500}\frac{1500}{50}\frac{(\frac{s}{1500}+1)}{(\frac{s}{50}+1)}$$

which is equivalent to above (and unity gain at DC). You could also just find the magnitude (dB) of the second form and plot it, but it's more convenient to put the pole and zero in the first form and plot it, then doing these derivations.

Comment: Is that the rule were each numerator and denominator each needs a +1?

Comment: Does that re-write  give unity gain at DC?